# RegExp match balise [] with A-Z 0-9 inside

Tags: php, regex

Say I have something like:

```
$content = " some text [TAG_123] and other text";
```

I want to match `[TAG_123]`.

To be more precise : `[` followed by one uppercase `A-Z` , followed by zero or several `0-9A-Z_`, followed by `]`.

I tried :

```
$reg = "/\[[A-Z]+[0-9A-Z_]*/"; // => this match [TAG_123

$reg = "/\[[A-Z]+[0-9A-Z_]*\]/"; // => this doesn't work ???
```

Comment: you forgot the underscore `[0-9A-Z_]` - first match is [TAG not [TAG_123

Comment: Yes, forgot '_' I updated, but problem is same

Comment: One uppercase A-Z? You already have three.

Comment: first after [ must be mandatary A-Z, after follow by zero or more A-Z0-9_

Comment: NOTE: if your trying to match Tag_123 you need to specify case-insensitive with an `i` "/regexp/i" OR use a-zA-Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the underscore in you regular expression:

```
$reg = "/\[[A-Z]+[0-9A-Z]*/"; // => this matches [TAG and not [TAG_123
```

Also you need to remove the `+` from `[A-Z]` as it is only needed once.

```
<?php
$content = " some text [TAG_123] and other text";

$regs="/\[[A-Z][0-9A-Z]*/";
preg_match($regs, $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);

$regs="/\[[A-Z][0-9A-Z_]*/";
preg_match($regs, $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);

$regs="/\[[A-Z][0-9A-Z_]*\]/";
preg_match($regs, $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

results

```
    Array ( [0] => [TAG )
    Array ( [0] => [TAG_123 )
    Array ( [0] => [TAG_123] )
```

Answer (score 0):

- `[A-Z]` : 1 letter, `A-Z`
- `[A-Z0-9_]*` : 0 or more, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`
- `\[` and `\]` : literally match `[` and `]`

---

```php
$content = " some text [TAG_123] and other text";
if (preg_match('/\[[A-Z][0-9A-Z_]*\]/', $content, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches); // $matches[0] includes [TAG_123]
}
```